# Get the name of installed program

Tags: wireless, software-installation

Interface Down.

Xubuntu. Is there a Terminal command that will list a program that I newly downloaded from https://github.com/blueman-project/blueman. I'm sure the program is good but it was not what I needed, and I suspect it causing the message "Interface Down" and I want to delete it since it didn't enable Bluetooth on my Laptop anyway. Maybe that will restore my internet connection.

Comment: How did you download it?? wget ?

Comment: try `sudo apt search <part-of-name-with-an-asterisk*>` that should give you the full name then use `sudo apt remove <full-program-name>` the link is bad .. i even tried github.com but blueman doesn't have anything there.

Comment: I downloaded it:  Settings-Bluetooth Manager-Enable Bluetooth-Help-About-https://gifhub.com/blueman-projekt/blueman

Comment: Ok, I will try that, but I want be able to comment on it before I try Iit out at home. I'm on a library without my Xubuntu Laptop.

Comment: I don't have bluetooth on my linux box so I can't find the actual address to see what you downloaded and how it was installed but hopefully the above will work for you. If you downloaded it and then had to install it via a .deb file .. then you can use the same program that installed the .deb file ... if you try to install the .deb file again it will usually tell you its installed and give you an option to remove it (in a GUI program if that is what was used)

Comment: You are right about the bad link, meaning I can´t get access to that site to see the name of the program I downloaded. It's the latest one so could there be a Terminal command listing downloaded programs with the newlist first?

Comment: when  you say you downloaded it .. what did you do after you downloaded it ... did it automatically install ... or did you have to do something? is tthis the site [https://github.com/blueman-project/blueman](https://github.com/blueman-project/blueman)

Comment: It ask me to type my password.

Comment: and I did that.

Comment: Yes it's the site

Comment: How did you install the program? That will determine how to remove it. Please [edit] your question, when you want to add information. It's best to have everything relevant in one place. Additionally, comments may be deleted for various reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

all you need to do is use

```
sudo apt-get remove blueman
```

This will remove it .. if you want to remove it and any dependent packages which are no longer needed  use

```
sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove blueman
```

That will do it for you.

Comment: Ok I will do that and I will reply when I have done that. I will have to be at home.

Comment: I succesfully deleated all blueman files on my Laptop. 29 files. Thanks John